# Download and store data offline in Cordova hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, blackberry, mean-stack

I am building a hybrid app using Cordova, Ionic framework and MEAN stack. The functionalities of the app are similar to that of Quiz Up app in which the user is supposed to answer some multiple choice questions. 
What I want to do is to provide the user an option to download the questions for an exam from the internet and solve them later **(user can be offline while solving them)**. So where and how should I store the downloaded questions and access them later?  
**The solution should support atleast Android, iOS, Blackberry and Windows Phone platforms.**

Comment: You can download all data at the user login and use them in your app, even offline, I can't see the issue

Comment: Probably I didn't explain the problem correctly. 
What I want to know is what method of data storage should be most suitable in this case? 
should I store it in WebSQL, store the data in a text file in SD card or what?

Comment: Well, if I be in you, I'd store all data using LocalStorageDB (link: https://github.com/knadh/localStorageDB). You can use it as a lite DB, permanent or temporary as you wish